# Python: How to create new columns in a df based on values of other columns within the df

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to coding so this could be a total beginners mistake but I'm using python in order to analyze some data. I currently have a dataframe that looks similar to this: 
`df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['2010-03-04', '2010-04-02',  '2010-03-04','2010-04-02','2010-03-04','2010-04-02'],
                   'A': ['1', '1', '2', '2','3','3'],
                    'B': ['40', '3', '49', '42','13', '20']})` 
and that prints:

```
          Date                A               B
  0       2010-03-04          1               40 
  1       2010-04-02          1               3
  2       2010-03-04          2               49 
  3       2010-04-02          2               42
  4       2010-03-04          3               13
  5       2010-04-02          3               20
```

but I want something that looks like this:

```
        Date                A 1              A 2               A 3
  0      2010-03-04          40               49               13
  1      2010-04-02           3               42               20
```

I've tried the `groupby` function but I'm not sure if that's even what I should be doing. The code for that is:

```
gb = df.groupby('A')    
[gb.get_group(x) for x in gb.groups]
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you used with `groupby`?

Comment: @HarvIpan I added it to the main post. I'm not exactly sure if that's what I should be doing as it does split the df up but im not sure how to take that data and make new columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot` and some renaming:

```
df_out = df.pivot('date','A','B')
df_out.add_prefix(df_out.columns.name).reset_index().rename_axis([None], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
         date  A1  A2  A3
0  2010-03-04  40  49  13
1  2010-04-02   3  42  20
```